# Doesn't this just return the original size?

Tags: c, operating-system, malloc

I'm trying to figure out what this code does. I'm analyzing my professor's malloc code and he has this function in his code. I don't get why he does though. To me it just returns the same amount of allocated space.

```
static inline size_t word_align(size_t size) {
    return size + (sizeof(size_t) - 1) & ~(sizeof(size_t) - 1);
}
```

Comment: It rounds up to a multiple of sizeof(size_t)

Comment: The obvious thing for you to do here is *test* it.  Call it on values from, say, 0 through 16 and see what you get.  You can also look at the value of `sizeof(size_t)`.  None of this requires posting a question here.  When you say "to me it just returns the same amount of allocated space", that seems to imply that you did all of this and found that it always returns the same number it is given.  But clearly, it does not.

Answer (score 4):

You could have seen this for yourself: a simple example shows the word alignment.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t word_align(size_t size)
{
    return size + (sizeof(size_t) - 1) & ~(sizeof(size_t) - 1);
}

int main(void)
{
    size_t i;
    for (i=1; i<10; i++)
       printf("%zu %zu\n", i, word_align(i));
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
1 4
2 4
3 4
4 4
5 8
6 8
7 8
8 8
9 12
```

Comment: This is exactly what OP should have done for him/herself before posting.  This will also vary from one system to anothing depending on the size of `size_t`, but the basic character of what it does will be the same.

Comment: For some reason, I had myself convinced that `&` had operator precedence over `+` and couldn't figure out for the life of me why it was doing anything... Figured it out eventually, though.

Answer (score 1):

The code is doing **8-byte alignment for the requested memory**. This is a common practice in systems programming, and a classic technique.

Why it is done? From Wikipedia:

> Data alignment means putting the data at a memory address equal to
>   some multiple of the word size, which increases the system's
>   performance due to the way the CPU handles memory.

To understand the code better parenthesizing to make the operator precedence of '+' and '&' explicit.

`(size + (sizeof(size_t) - 1))   &   ~(sizeof(size_t) - 1)`

Given that `sizeof(size_t) = 8`, and `size = 170`, what the code does is:

`(170 + 8) & ~(0x7)`

Thus, the `~(sizeof(size_t) - 1)` acts as 3-bit mask.